Google Contacts showing 2 conflicting count values
I have an Android phone. I check my Google Contacts on the web application and I am surprised to find that it is showing two different values for the number of contacts I have!
Looks like the contacts are there because when I do search for a name, I can find it but the number in the top is sure confusing me. Is there a reason that 2 different counts are showing?
Note: I have seen another question where the reason could have been the existence of a blank contact record, but I don't have this case.
Is it possible that the (1) record has a tag different that the rest and that Google Contacts Show contacts by a given tag at any time and not all contacts?

